# Is there anyway to have the key of a HashMap match up to a WPF tool name?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, sqlite, hashmap

Title wasn't too worded well because I'm unsure of how to articulate my problem, but I'm creating an app in WPF C# and I'm using HashMaps to save and load data from a Sqlite db. I've named my fields for my XAML the same as the columns names in the SQLite db and I would like to load these values to the textboxes on my app when the component is initialized.

Example: (How I currently have it, very tedious and seems inefficient)

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in dataToLoad)
            {
                switch (entry.Key)
                {
                    case "tsd_vac_on":
                        tsd_vac_on.Text = entry.Value;
                        break;

                    case "tsd_vac_off":
                        tsd_vac_off.Text = entry.Value;
                        break;
                }
            }
```

Ideally this is how I would like it done where the key name of the entry is already the same name as the textbox I'm trying to edit.

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in dataToLoad)
            {
                (entry.Key).Text = entry.Value;
            }
}
```

Comment: `((TextBox)FindName(entry.Key)).Text = entry.Value;`

Comment: @Clemens That was it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `FindName` method to access the named element, like

```
if (FindName(entry.Key) is TextBox textBox)
{
    textBox.Text = entry.Value;
}
```